# ASP.NET - Content, Styles, Scripts, Images, Resources folders are not getting copied over to Publish folder while Publishing (for deployment)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I am a new-ish solo developer in a company, and I am trying to deploy an existing ASP.NET website to Dev and Prod environments. I think this is a WebForms project (I am not sure how to figure out what kind of project this is tbh).

When I Publish the website to a folder using Visual Studio, everything but the Content, Styles, Scripts, Images, Resources folders get published properly. As a result, after deploying on IIS, the website loads with just HTML, no styles, themes or images. I have to manually copy those folders over from the code repo to the Publish folder after publishing is done.

How can I fix this?

Tools: ASP.NET, Web Forms (I think?), Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that you are working and attempting to maintain this web site as a web site applcation.

Keep in mind that a Web site?

This has all of the folders and includes your css files etc. This folder is ASSUMED to be a 100% valid working copy of the web site. Often developers will open the web site "live" on the hosted server directly. This is not a great idea, but it is VERY easy, since you can say open up a web page, modify it, and save, and you are DONE!!!

In effect, no real publish is required. You have a full working web site that the web server (IIS) is running against.

if you want to work on a copy, then you can/would copy the whole web site from the wwwroot or whatever folder the IIS web site is CURRETLY consuming and using.

You can then ALWAYS open the web site using file->open web site. You NEVER and DO NOT in ANY case want to open that web site as a web site project or so called applcation. (that would be the prj, or sln file).

However, it is possible that you have a asp.net web site applcation. (the key concept/word here is "applcation".

For a application, then yes, you REALLY need to use web site publish. That publish will compile all the code, remove the c# (or vb.net) code, compile those to .dll's. That resulting folder publish will thus have MANY parts removed, including source code, and the code will have been pre-compiled by Visual studio as opposed to letting the web site (IIS) do the compile of such code.

And with this choice, you of course have to mark/check/set/ensure/control/be aware/know/   that any additional folder has to be marked as part of the project. In fact VS should show such folders as "grayed" out, and not to be part of the publish process.

Say, I have a folder with a bunch of css and other files. So, right click on that folder and check the settings.

let's say do this from VS for a folder I have called content. (lots of css and other things in that folder in my case). And this is a "applicaiton"

So, right click, and check this:

[image]

NOTE very close in above - "Exclude" from project.

also, you can right click on ANY file in that folder, and display property sheet, and you have these options (which publish will use).

So, i right clicked on the file called Burke.css, and we then get this:

[image]

So, check those options for those missing files. And check the options for the folder(s) (include/exclude from project).

My spider sense suggests that this was a web site, and you trying to work/change/develop/use this web site as a web site project.

You can certainly covert over time to a "application", and while I prefer a "applcation" over a web site, often many prefer a web site, since it does not really require you to use the publish options at all.

You can super easy find out - just look at the web site running on IIS - does it include the vb.net (or c#) files on that site? If thsoe code behind files exist, then you have a web site, and not a web site applcation.